# What type of Mimosoidea is this?

Tags: identification

What is this plant with yellow blooms? I have been told it is a type of [Mimosoidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimosoideae), but would like to know more definitely. The blooms on this specimen were approx. 3-4 cm in diameter. I have encountered it (as is usual for me these days) in Central Europe.

[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced its one of the Mimosoidea at all, they usually all have pinnate leaves - are there any thorns on the plant?  Are the flowers fragrant? How tall was it?

Comment: @Bamboo I saw the plant on a hike; did not check for thorns or fragrance at the time, so unfortunatelly I can't tell you that. In terms of size it was approx. 1m tall. It was described to me as a type of *Akazie* (in German), which TMK translates into *Mimosoidea* in English (well, Latin :) This lead could be wrong, of course.

Comment: Funny, when I checked Akazie, it came up with Robinia, Acacia or a shittah tree... its not any of those. Not at all sure what it is... and akazie might be a common or pet name, and they're rarely any use at all!  I'm curious as to what it is though, I don't recognise it

Comment: I think the answer you've been given is probably pretty close - Cassia bicapularis has similar flowers, though the distinctive veination on the leaves is missing https://toptropicals.com/catalog/uid/SENNA_BICAPSULARIS.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience tells me this plant is a Cassia, in subfamily Caesalpinioides, (along with subfamily Mimosoideae in Leguminosae). But Chamaecrista (Cassia) genus is quite large. I once grew Chamaecrista fasciculata (Partridge Pea) but this is not it, on C. fasciculata the leaflets are smaller, more numerous and closely spaced. It does have the characteristic terminal twin leaflets. This one is more like C. glandulosa. But that is about as close as I can get. Others will no doubt have one in their back yard and pin it down.

Comment: Yes, a [Cassia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassia_(genus)) or [Senna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senna_(plant)), that must be it. Perhaps its a [Senna alexandrina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senna_alexandrina). Thank you very much for the lead.